# dynamic range in arrayformula without using indirect?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I have this formula in spreadsheet that works as supposed. The formula is placed in "O:O" (this one is from O10).
(I've translated the formula from danish - hope I did it right)

```
=IFERROR(IF(I10<>"";sum(INDIRECT("L"&MATCH(LEFT(B10;LEN(B10)-6);B:B;0)):INDIRECT("L"&ROW()-1));"");"Fejl/Mangler reference")
```

Here's the result
[image]

The data is imported from another sheet and the lines can change over time and there can be added/removed rows that should be taken into consideration in each Sub Total.

This is why I want to convert the formula to an arrayformula - or another solution?

What I thought would work was:

```
=Arrayformula(IF(ROW(R:R)=5;"Balance";IF(ROW(R:R)<7;"";IF(ROW(R:R)=7;"Sub Total";IF($I:$I<>"";sum(INDIRECT("L"&MATCH(LEFT(B:B;LEN(B:B)-6);B:B;0))&":"&INDIRECT("L"&ROW()-1));"")))))
```

I guess is the Indirect so I've tried also to do it with a vlookup but that I couldn't figure out either.

Any good ideas?

Here's a link for the document: [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ahILu3-4pFuuP4Mi5uK8QeaBg_sPa07QokMvqtqj_AY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cell **P8**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J8:J="";; SUMIF(ROW(O8:O); "<="&ROW(O8:O); O8:O)))
```

cell **O8**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I8:I="";;
 SUMIF(ROW(B8:B); "<="&ROW(B8:B); L8:L)-SUMIF(ROW(B8:B); "<"&VLOOKUP(
 VLOOKUP(ROW(B8:B); IF(B8:B<>""; {ROW(B8:B)\ SUBSTITUTE(B8:B; " i alt"; )}); 2; 1); {
 VLOOKUP(ROW(B8:B); IF(B8:B<>""; {ROW(B8:B)\ SUBSTITUTE(B8:B; " i alt"; )}); 2; 1)\
 ROW(B8:B)}; 2; 0); L8:L)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. The P8 though doesn't seems to work as supposed. I'll try to dig into it myself... But it should refer to the titles in Column A. Do pretty much the same as O8.

Comment: I've just adapted your O8. Changed I to J, B to A and L to O and it works. Hurray! Thanks again. Now I'll try to understand it also ;-)